# how to write a pair space delimited to a text file in python?

Tags: python

I have a space delimited string Like :

```
-50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367 -27.833419404448 2320.329844569581 -26.805460276239 2320.302239847568 -26.661859170481 2320.383218590322 -26.369639786391 2320.285153586396 -20.533526952571 2320.307048549957 -18.430372069319 2320.322131347984 -17.682267511693 2320.183044082935 -9.412365074428 2318.640728018348 -4.39105022394 2318.702274658016 -2.799896950857 2319.050216505886 -1.650828549365 2318.851729275538 0.000000000007 2318.821619902524 0.924165106416 2318.804764104907 4.836725761028 2319.15202498789 7.95861459112 2319.5814968401 9.681527521478 2320.446202236106 16.837024777724 2320.776558542595 22.698760541826 2320.670478882793 28.2917471128 2320.68119460127 34.902349455571 2320.270498276339 41.416761759252 2319.105567597744 46.219145248796 2318.698663233488 50.000000000015 2318.45911198918
```

in a variable.
I want to export this to a text file like:

```
-50 2320.034873495636
-37.028592075933 2320.742117324367
-27.833419404448 2320.329844569581
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hi! What did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Split string every three words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204225/python-split-string-every-three-words)

Answer (score 3):

You can split the data, then use an iterator on the resulting list that lets you iterate and also get the next value in the loop:

```
data = '-50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367'
values = iter(data.split())

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for val in values:
        f.write(f'{val} {next(values)}\n')
```

File content:

```
-50. 2320.034873495636
-37.028592075933 2320.742117324367
```

And of course, if your data is invalid and you have an odd number of values, you'll get an error (`StopIteration`).

---

This first approach is really interesting if you have an iterator in the first place. As we have a list, a more classic approach could be to zip the list of items with even indices with the list of items with odd indices:

```
data = '-50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367 6'
values = data.split()

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for val1, val2 in zip(values[::2], values[1::2]):
        f.write(f'{val1} {val2}\n')
```

which gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a list within a list.

First of all you delimit each pair with the '-'.
After you have created this list you then delimit each element of the list (which in your case will be the pairs of coordinates), you can use space indentation.

So to recap.

1) Split the entire list by using the '-' as a delimiter.
2) Split the elements of the list by using the empty space.

I haven't included any code sample here because I encourage you to try and implement this yourself by using the strip() and split() functions which are implemented into python2 and python3.

Comment: As you can see the `-` is present in the file, if you split according to it it will be gone

Comment: why split "-"? its negative sign for value.

Comment: I though that the '-' meant a pair of coordinates. Is that correct?

Comment: @Tomerikoo You can do a simple sorting algorithm where you can put it back automatically after using It to split. In this case that's the only thing that you can use to split.

Comment: No it is not the only thing. It doesn't make a lot of sense to put something down just to put it back...

Comment: @Mohammad Then I think the only solution Is to create a counting function and split them after a certain number has been reached, that Is only If the values are represented by a 0 i.e: -37.000000000000 2320.000000000000

Comment: @Tomerikoo The reason Is so you can split It, because as you can see, there aren't a lot of ways to split this string except the two methods I mentioned.

Comment: @Tomerikoo It seems a fair answer, although It suits just the case above and will break with a little input tweak. However,  I respect the above answer and voted It.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` to turn the string into a 1d list, then iterate over every *other* element and write them to the file in pairs.

```
inpstr = "-50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367 -27.833419404448 2320.329844569581 -26.805460276239 2320.302239847568 -26.661859170481 2320.383218590322 -26.369639786391 2320.285153586396 -20.533526952571 2320.307048549957 -18.430372069319 2320.322131347984 -17.682267511693 2320.183044082935 -9.412365074428 2318.640728018348 -4.39105022394 2318.702274658016 -2.799896950857 2319.050216505886 -1.650828549365 2318.851729275538 0.000000000007 2318.821619902524 0.924165106416 2318.804764104907 4.836725761028 2319.15202498789 7.95861459112 2319.5814968401 9.681527521478 2320.446202236106 16.837024777724 2320.776558542595 22.698760541826 2320.670478882793 28.2917471128 2320.68119460127 34.902349455571 2320.270498276339 41.416761759252 2319.105567597744 46.219145248796 2318.698663233488 50.000000000015 2318.45911198918"
inplst = inpstr.split(" ")
with open("outputfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
  for i in range(0, len(inplst), 2):
    outfile.write(f"{float(inplst[i])} {float(inplst[i + 1])}\n")
```

This may produce an `IndexError` if your `inpstr` has an odd number of numbers.

Comment: its always pair numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
_str = "50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367 -27.833419404448 2320.329844569581 -26.805460276239 2320.302239847568 -26.661859170481 2320.383218590322 -26.369639786391 2320.285153586396 -20.533526952571 2320.307048549957 -18.430372069319 2320.322131347984 -17.682267511693 2320.183044082935 -9.412365074428 2318.640728018348 -4.39105022394 2318.702274658016 -2.799896950857 2319.050216505886 -1.650828549365 2318.851729275538 0.000000000007 2318.821619902524 0.924165106416 2318.804764104907 4.836725761028 2319.15202498789 7.95861459112 2319.5814968401 9.681527521478 2320.446202236106 16.837024777724 2320.776558542595 22.698760541826 2320.670478882793 28.2917471128 2320.68119460127 34.902349455571 2320.270498276339 41.416761759252 2319.105567597744 46.219145248796 2318.698663233488 50.000000000015 2318.45911198918"
_list = _str.split()
pair_list = []
for i in range(0, len(_list), 2):
    pair_list.append(' '.join(_list[i:i+2]))
with open('pairs.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in pair_list:
        f.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` as in:

```
fin = "-50. 2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933 2320.742117324367 -27.833419404448 2320.329844569581 -26.805460276239 2320.302239847568 -26.661859170481 2320.383218590322 -26.369639786391 2320.285153586396 -20.533526952571 2320.307048549957 -18.430372069319 2320.322131347984 -17.682267511693 2320.183044082935 -9.412365074428 2318.640728018348 -4.39105022394 2318.702274658016 -2.799896950857 2319.050216505886 -1.650828549365 2318.851729275538 0.000000000007 2318.821619902524 0.924165106416 2318.804764104907 4.836725761028 2319.15202498789 7.95861459112 2319.5814968401 9.681527521478 2320.446202236106 16.837024777724 2320.776558542595 22.698760541826 2320.670478882793 28.2917471128 2320.68119460127 34.902349455571 2320.270498276339 41.416761759252 2319.105567597744 46.219145248796 2318.698663233488 50.000000000015 2318.45911198918"

fout = "\n".join(f"{x} {y}"
                 for splitted in [fin.split(" ")]
                 for x, y in zip(splitted, splitted[1:]))
print(fout)
```

Which yields

```
-50. 2320.034873495636
2320.034873495636 -37.028592075933
-37.028592075933 2320.742117324367
2320.742117324367 -27.833419404448
...
```